# django.db.utils.programmingerror cannot cast time without time zone to timestamp with timezone

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I am trying to migrate my django project to heroku and this error came up:

```
django.db.utils.programmingerror cannot cast time without time zone to timestamp with timezone
```

here is picture:

[image]

[image]

```
git push heroku master
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

My pip freeze should be right and all others also.

Should I import time zone in `models.py`?

Comment: Copy and paste your `models.py` and migrations file here.

Comment: Hey, where can i see migration files?. I usually just type manage.py migrate

Comment: They're in your app's migrations directory.

Comment: which one of these: http://puu.sh/npTGN/de95f21817.jpg